# Resetting auto-increment column back to 0 daily

Tags: database, postgresql, auto-increment

Is there a way in postgresql to have an auto-incrementing column reset back to zero at a specified time every day?

Comment: why would you want to do that? could you add more info please. Rather than state your perceived solution, tell us what the real problem is.

Comment: Seeing as Postgres got ranking functions in 8.4, a better idea would be to rank based on a timestamp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be pretty trivial with a cronjob

```
0 0 * * * echo "SELECT setval('public.my_table_id_seq', 1, false)" | psql -U my_db_user -d my_db_name
```

Alternately, you could set your "serial" column DEFAULT to call a stored procedure, which would check for a day rollover, reset the sequence if appropriate, and then return the result of nextval().

But other than that, no, I wouldn't expect that there's a magic ALTER SEQUENCE my_seq RESET AT INERVAL '1 day' or anything like that.

Edit: incorporated duckyfuzz's comment.

Comment: When I tried this, I got a "setval: value 0 is out of bounds for sequence "searches_id_seq"" error. The solution is to use the three parameter version of seval() like this: setval('public. my_table_id_seq', 1, false). Read more here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html

Comment: If uniqueness is required, this is unreliable since it could theoretically reset just after a record has been inserted at the start of the day.

Answer (score 7):

Basicaly you can reset sequence with this one:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE your_sequence_name RESTART WITH 1;
```

Enjoy...

Comment: I like this way, it's easier to remember.

Comment: ok for reseting but for reseting everyday at 00:00 ?